# Scanner Daily Duty Cycle

Tags: scanner, scanning

I'm comfused with the concept of 'Daily Duty Cycle'. For example if I have a scanner that the spec is: PPM (pages per minute): 90 and DDC (Daily Duty Cycle): 800.
I am interested in scanning ONLY 10 hours continuously, what would it be the best choice:

90 * 60 * 10 = 54.000

or

(800 / 24) * 10 = 333

It is very different results. what would it be the best option?

Comment: i've merged the migrated copy of your SO question into this question.  in the future, please don't crosspost; if you post to the wrong site the post can be migrated to the proper site.

Comment: and how do I makes notes or new questions in the same post?

Comment: you can edit your own questions (there is an "edit" link some 5cm up, and 2cm left of the this word --> "edit" <-- in my comment)

Answer (score 2):

It means that it is a relatively low volume scanner.  It can scan up to 90 pages per minute, but the components aren't meant to be in continuous operation.  To get the normal life out of the device, you wouldn't want to scan more than 800 pages per day on average.  If you expect to regularly scan more than that, you should get a scanner with a higher duty cycle rating.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the duty cycle calculation is based on MTBF of a scanner in five years. So it means if you want the scanner to the job everyday thorugh out the year and you want your scanner to be OK in next five years you should follow the duty cycle rules.But if you are doing project (in just 1-2 days , 1-3 months) then calculating the productivity using duty cycle will be an expensive investment.

Usually for continuous scanning my calculation will be 75% (reduce productivity on scanner) x speed in ppm x 60 minutes x 10 hours, that will be a most likey productivity on scanner with skilled operator. For regular operator I would choose 55-60% for a factor.

Answer (score 0):

As you've calculated, if you use it at peak load (90ppm) for 10 hours, you will scan 54,000 pages a day. 
That is obviously a lot more than the daily duty cycle of 800, so this is not the scanner for you.